# Catching links from other applications in a basic android browser

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm developing a web browser (from a tutorial) ,lets call it X and don't have too much experience with Android SDK.

I'm trying to catch a link and browse to it from X .

I've removed all browsers from the device and set X to default browser but still I can't open links from Google App in X, Google app gives output `"No applications found to open this url"`.
What's going wrong, I've set category to browsable using `<intent-filter>` .

Besides that I'm unable to understand the concept of indents from official documentations so I'm unable to handle the intent data even if X receives it. Please provide some resources that might help me, googling didn't find me something I can understand is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your intent filter isn't specifying that is van handle ACTION_VIEW on all http and https links.  Try this, from the manifest of android's open source browser:

```
        <!-- For these schemes were not particular MIME type has been
             supplied, we are a good candidate. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:scheme="about" />
            <data android:scheme="javascript" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!--  For these schemes where any of these particular MIME types
              have been supplied, we are a good candidate. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:scheme="inline" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/html"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/xhtml+xml"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml"/>
        </intent-filter>
```